# Oracle SQL Count with group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables

| person_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

| item_id | person_id | item_valid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | null |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | null |

I wish to get the percentage of valid item / total number of items owned by a person.

For example in this case, I want

| person_id | percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50% |
| 2 | 100% |
| 3 | 0% |

How can I do this with a single select statement with subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't even need the 1st table; you *might* need it if there were people without any rows in the 2nd table (so you'd outer join these two tables) or if you'd want to display some additional data (names, ...).

With the 2nd table only, there's no need for subqueries - everything can be done in a single select statement.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (item_id, person_id, item_valid) as
  2    (select 2, 1, 1    from dual union all
  3     select 1, 1, null from dual union all
  4     select 3, 2, 1    from dual union all
  5     select 4, 3, null from dual
  6    )
```

Query: conditional aggregation (the `sum` function) calculates number of valid items; it is then divided by total number of rows per person.

```
  7  select person_id,
  8    sum(case when item_valid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) / count(*) * 100 percentage
  9  from test
 10  group by person_id;

 PERSON_ID PERCENTAGE
---------- ----------
         1         50
         2        100
         3          0

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might conditionally count just before applying percentage such as

```
SELECT person_id, 100*SUM(NVL(item_valid,0))/ COUNT(*)||'%' AS percentage    
  FROM t
 GROUP BY person_id
```

presuming the *invalid* ones flagged as **null** or **zero**

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/A47dOZAP)</kbd>